# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce Questions

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to implement the Enhanced Ecommerce tracking with Google Analytics and ran into a few questions.

1. Can you only send impressions with the pageview event? So how would I send impressions of items loaded after the initial pageview event?
2. I wanted to send product impressions on search result pages, which are in blocks of 10. When I try to send along with the pageview, it never sends, I'm guessing because it's too long for Google, so how would I send multiple at 1 time? I can get upto 6 products and have it still work.
3. Should I just use an event to track impressions? Would this solve the sending and size issue if I made a call for each product?

Any guidance would be appreciated. I feel the documentation is lacking a bit with some specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to necessarily send ecomm data with the pageview. As stated here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce, in the "Sending Enhanced Ecommerce Data" section:

> Note: Ecommerce data can only be sent with an existing hit, for example a pageview or event. If you use ecommerce commands but do not send any hits, or the hit is sent before the ecommerce command then the ecommerce data will not be sent.

There's also more information in this SO post: [Tracking catalog product impressions - Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140579/tracking-catalog-product-impressions-enhanced-ecommerce-google-analytics).

I'm not sure if there is a hit limit for EE transactions as there are for other types of hits (limit of 500 hits per session), but if you are worried that you'll reach some limit, whether it's EE or not, or if you think you'll send more than 20 hits per second, then you can throttle the hits being sent to Google.